# NetworkImageView set image from file

Tags: java, android, image, networkimageview

I have a `NetworkImageView` which loads its content from a URL, but in a specific case I also want to be able to load an image from the user's Gallery (or even capture one with the camera).

I'm using [Image Chooser Library](https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library) to load the image from the gallery, and after choosing, it allows me to get the file path of the image. This path is something like `/mnt/sdcard/bimagechooser/IMG_20140811_155007906.jpg`

If I try to load the image directly from this path, Volley will raise an exception stating:

> NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL `/mnt/sdcard/bimagechooser/IMG_20140811_155007906.jpg`

I also tried setting the drawable:

```
Drawable newImage = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
mNetworkImageView.setImageDrawable(newImage);
```

Nothing happens when these lines run, the view remains empty/unchanged.

What is the correct way to set the `NetworkImageView` content without a URL?

Comment: You still think that that is possible? Show appropriate documentation please.

Comment: Well, at least the `setImageDrawable` should work, since the class extends `ImageView`

Comment: I see now that it is from Volley library (you could have mentioned that) and extends indeed ImageView. So you can do all what is possible with ImageView.  Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: That's what I thought, but apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: Correct, it does not work, see my answer below for info.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that `setImageDrawable` does not work is because in `onLayout` and `setImageUrl` call the private method `loadImageIfNecessary`, which will call another private method `setDefaultImageOrNull` if there was no image url provided. This wipes out whatever you set via `setImageDrawable`.

Volley's NetworkImageView code...

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    loadImageIfNecessary(true);
}

void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
    ...

    // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old requests and clear the
    // currently loaded image.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        setDefaultImageOrNull();
        return;
    }
    ...
}

private void setDefaultImageOrNull() {
    if(mDefaultImageId != 0) {
        setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
    }
    else {
        setImageBitmap(null);
    }
}
```

You can do as @mmlooloo suggests and manually add your image to the image cache OR you create your own "NetworkImageView" based off of Volley's and have `onLayout` NOT call `loadImageIfNecessary` when no url is provided. You can then override the ImageView setters  `setImageDrawable` and `setImageURI` to set the url to null. You can then use setImageDrawable and setImageURI as you normally would with ImageView.

NOTE: You may run into issues if you override `setImageBitmap` or `setImageResource` methods as these are called within `loadImageIfNecessary`. I have not run into issues yet, however I have not done much testing.

Your class...

```
public class MyNetworkImageView extends ImageView {

//Copy the code from Volley's NetworkImageView and change onLayout as below.

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
        loadImageIfNecessary(true);
    }else{
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
    }
}

//Change the other ImageView image setters, for example...
@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mUrl = null;
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

@Override
public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    mUrl = null;
    super.setImageURI(uri);
}    

}
```

Comment: I decided to avoid the `setImageResource` potential conflict since you can work around it by using `setImageDrawable` anyway... something like `final Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resId);                    networkOrLocalImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);`  The answer above worked for my purposes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it worth trying:

when you create memory cache for your mImageLoader keep it somewhere, now create cache key for your

image by this code:

```
    private static String getCacheKey(String url, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    return new StringBuilder(url.length() + 12).append("#W").append(maxWidth)
            .append("#H").append(maxHeight).append(url).toString();
}
```

after that put your image into the cache by calling :

```
 mCache.putBitmap(cacheKey, response);
```

then again send your url to NetworkImageView, Volley will find your url in his cache and return it to you.

I hope it helps!!

Comment: The `url` param is the file path?

Comment: i do not think that makes any problem because you have already put the bitmap in his cache and he would never make any network request, first he looks at his cache and if he finds the image he gets it and thats all.

Comment: I still don't understand what URL I am supposed to use, how/when to add the image to the cache

Comment: any fake URL will work, before calling NetworkImage(setImgURL, mImageLoader); in your getView, you must put your drables in his cache and then replace your fake url by setImgURL for that row.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: No, I ended up subclassing `NetworkImageView` and fixing the problem within it.